# R : how to get the rolling mean of a variable over the last few days but only at a given hour?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lubridate

Consider this

```
time <- seq(ymd_hms("2014-02-24 23:00:00"), ymd_hms("2014-06-25 08:32:00"), by="hour")
group <- rep(LETTERS[1:20], each = length(time))
value <- sample(-10^3:10^3,length(time), replace=TRUE)
df2 <- data.frame(time,group,value)
str(df2)

> head(df2)
                 time group value
1 2014-02-24 23:00:00     A   246
2 2014-02-25 00:00:00     A  -261
3 2014-02-25 01:00:00     A   628
4 2014-02-25 02:00:00     A   429
5 2014-02-25 03:00:00     A   -49
6 2014-02-25 04:00:00     A  -749
```

I would like to create a variable that contains, for each group, the **rolling mean** of `value`

- over the last 5 days (not including the current observation)
- **only** considering observations that fall a*t the exact same hour* as the current observation.

In other words:

At time `2014-02-24 23:00:00`, `df2['rolling_mean_same_hour']` contains the mean of the values of `value` observed at `23:00:00` during the last 5 days in the data (not including `2014-02-24` of course).

I would like to do that in either `dplyr` or `data.table`. I confess having no ideas how to do that.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the `rollmean()` with your data grouped by the `group` variable and `hour` of the time variable, normally the `rollmean()` will include the current observation, but you can use `shift()` function to exclude the current observation from the `rollmean`:

```
library(data.table); library(zoo)
setDT(df2)
df2[, .(rolling_mean_same_hour = shift(
                                       rollmean(value, 5, na.pad = TRUE, align = 'right'), 
                                       n = 1, 
                                       type = 'lag'), 
        time), .(hour(time), group)]

#       hour group rolling_mean_same_hour                time
#    1:   23     A                     NA 2014-02-24 23:00:00
#    2:   23     A                     NA 2014-02-25 23:00:00
#    3:   23     A                     NA 2014-02-26 23:00:00
#    4:   23     A                     NA 2014-02-27 23:00:00
#    5:   23     A                     NA 2014-02-28 23:00:00
#   ---                                                      
#57796:   22     T                 -267.0 2014-06-20 22:00:00
#57797:   22     T                 -389.6 2014-06-21 22:00:00
#57798:   22     T                 -311.6 2014-06-22 22:00:00
#57799:   22     T                 -260.0 2014-06-23 22:00:00
#57800:   22     T                  -26.8 2014-06-24 22:00:00
```

Comment: Fwiw, data.table also has a "time of day" format, `ITime`, so if the OP put the var in that format (two vars: IDate, ITime), they could group on that.